# wix toolset: Success page showing multiple headers

Tags: wix, installation, wix3, bootstrapper, wix3.9

I'm using the HyperlinkTheme.xml from [the WiX 3 github site](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/Resources/HyperlinkTheme.xml), with WiX v3.9 R2 to create my installer.  When I run my installer, it succeeds, but on the success page it shows all 4 headers overlaying each other (SuccessHeader, SuccessInstallHeader, SuccessRepairHeader, SuccessUninstallHeader).  I changed the Y values so they wouldn't display on top of each other:

[image]

How do I get it to only show only the pertinent header?

Here is my slightly altered version of HyperlinkTheme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Theme xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/thmutil/2010">
    <Window Width="485" Height="300" HexStyle="100a0000" FontId="0">#(loc.Caption)</Window>
    <Font Id="0" Height="-12" Weight="500" Foreground="000000" Background="FFFFFF">Segoe UI</Font>
    <Font Id="1" Height="-24" Weight="500" Foreground="000000">Segoe UI</Font>
    <Font Id="2" Height="-22" Weight="500" Foreground="666666">Segoe UI</Font>
    <Font Id="3" Height="-12" Weight="500" Foreground="000000" Background="FFFFFF">Segoe UI</Font>
    <Font Id="4" Height="-12" Weight="500" Foreground="ff0000" Background="FFFFFF" Underline="yes">Segoe UI</Font>

    <Image X="11" Y="11" Width="64" Height="64" ImageFile="logo.png" Visible="yes"/>
    <Text X="80" Y="11" Width="-11" Height="64" FontId="1" Visible="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.Title) #(loc.InstallVersion)</Text>

    <Page Name="Help">
        <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.HelpHeader)</Text>
        <Text X="11" Y="112" Width="-11" Height="-35" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.HelpText)</Text>
        <Button Name="HelpCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.HelpCloseButton)</Button>
    </Page>
    <Page Name="Install">        
        <Hypertext Name="EulaHyperlink" X="11" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="51" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallLicenseLinkText)</Hypertext>
        <Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-41" Width="260" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)</Checkbox>
        <Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallOptionsButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
    </Page>
    <Page Name="Options">
        <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OptionsHeader)</Text>
        <Text X="11" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OptionsLocationLabel)</Text>
        <Editbox Name="FolderEditbox" X="11" Y="143" Width="-91" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" FileSystemAutoComplete="yes" />
        <Button Name="BrowseButton" X="-11" Y="142" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">#(loc.OptionsBrowseButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="OptionsOkButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsOkButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="OptionsCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsCancelButton)</Button>
    </Page>
    <Page Name="Progress">
        <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.ProgressHeader)</Text>
        <Text X="11" Y="121" Width="70" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.ProgressLabel)</Text>
        <Text Name="OverallProgressPackageText" X="85" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OverallProgressPackageText)</Text>
        <Progressbar Name="OverallCalculatedProgressbar" X="11" Y="143" Width="-11" Height="15" />
        <Button Name="ProgressCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.ProgressCancelButton)</Button>
    </Page>
    <Page Name="Modify">
        <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.ModifyHeader)</Text>
        <Button Name="RepairButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.ModifyRepairButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="UninstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.ModifyUninstallButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="ModifyCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.ModifyCloseButton)</Button>
    </Page>
    <Page Name="Success">
        <Text Name="SuccessHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.SuccessHeader)</Text>
        <Text Name="SuccessInstallHeader" X="11" Y="100" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.SuccessInstallHeader)</Text>
        <Text Name="SuccessRepairHeader" X="11" Y="120" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.SuccessRepairHeader)</Text>     
        <Text Name="SuccessUninstallHeader" X="11" Y="140" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.SuccessUninstallHeader)</Text> 
        <Button Name="LaunchButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.SuccessLaunchButton)</Button>
        <Text Name="SuccessRestartText" X="-11" Y="-51" Width="400" Height="34" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.SuccessRestartText)</Text>
        <Button Name="SuccessRestartButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.SuccessRestartButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="SuccessCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.SuccessCloseButton)</Button>
    </Page>
    <Page Name="Failure">
        <Text Name="FailureHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureHeader)</Text>
        <Text Name="FailureInstallHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureInstallHeader)</Text>
        <Text Name="FailureUninstallHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureUninstallHeader)</Text>
        <Text Name="FailureRepairHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureRepairHeader)</Text>  
        <Hypertext Name="FailureLogFileLink" X="11" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="42" FontId="3" TabStop="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.FailureHyperlinkLogText)</Hypertext>
        <Hypertext Name="FailureMessageText" X="22" Y="163" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="3" TabStop="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes" />
        <Text Name="FailureRestartText" X="-11" Y="-51" Width="400" Height="34" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureRestartText)</Text>
        <Button Name="FailureRestartButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.FailureRestartButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="FailureCloseButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.FailureCloseButton)</Button>
    </Page>
</Theme>
```

Here is my bundle.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Map Creator" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="FMOsoft" UpgradeCode="GUID" Copyright="Copyright© 2015, FMOsoft">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
          <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            LocalizationFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\win\L10n\installer\thm_en_us.wxl"
            ThemeFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\win\HyperlinkTheme_fmosoft.xml"
            LogoFile="$(var.KarteDir)\assets\logo\bmp\logo_64.bmp"
            LogoSideFile="$(var.KarteDir)\assets\logo\png\icon_128.png"
            ShowVersion="yes"
            LicenseFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\license_en.html"
            LaunchTarget="[ProgramFiles6432Folder]\FMOsoft\MapCreator\MapCreator.exe"
            />

          <Payload Id="theme_en_us" Compressed="yes"  Name="1033\thm.wxl" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\win\L10n\installer\thm_en_us.wxl"/> 
          <Payload Id="license_en_us" Compressed="yes"  Name="1033\license.html" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\license_en.html"/> 
          <Payload Id="theme_es_es" Compressed="yes"  Name="1034\thm.wxl" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\win\L10n\installer\thm_es_es.wxl"/> 
          <Payload Id="license_es_es" Compressed="yes"  Name="1034\license.html" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\license_es.html"/> 
          <Payload Id="theme_fr_fr" Compressed="yes"  Name="1036\thm.wxl" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\win\L10n\installer\thm_fr_fr.wxl"/> 
          <Payload Id="license_fr_fr" Compressed="yes"  Name="1036\license.html" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\license_fr.html"/> 
          <Payload Id="theme_pt_br" Compressed="yes"  Name="1046\thm.wxl" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\win\L10n\installer\thm_pt_br.wxl"/>
          <Payload Id="license_pt_br" Compressed="yes"  Name="1046\license.html" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\license_pt.html"/> 
          <Payload Id="theme_id" Compressed="yes"  Name="1057\thm.wxl" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\win\L10n\installer\thm_id.wxl"/>
          <Payload Id="license_id" Compressed="yes"  Name="1057\license.html" SourceFile="$(var.KarteDir)\install\license_id.html"/> 
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseUrl" Value="license.html" />

        <Chain>
            <ExePackage SourceFile="vcredist_x64.exe" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart" InstallCondition="VersionNT64"/>
            <ExePackage SourceFile="vcredist_x86.exe" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart" InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64"/>
            <MsiPackage Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.BuildDir)out\map-creator-$(var.Platform).msi"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Here's how I build the installer:

```
"%WIXDIR%\candle.exe" bundle.wxs -dKarteDir="%KARTEDIR%" -dProductVersion=%PRODUCTVERSION% -dPlatform=%PLATFORM% -dBuildDir=%BUILDDIR% -out "obj\\" -ext WixBalExtension
"%WIXDIR%\light.exe" "obj\bundle.wixobj" -out "%BUILDDIR%\out\mc.exe" -ext WixBalExtension
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme from GitHub is from the develop branch and has changes from WiX v3.10 that the WixStdBA from v3.9 R2 doesn't know about. You can grab the v3.9 version from wix39-debug.zip on the [v3.9 R2 release page](https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/610859).

Comment: Thanks!  I should have thought of that.  I imagine I can get to the same thing by selecting the wix39r2 branch on github?  Or is there a reason I should use the wix39-debug.zip instead?

Comment: Usually, we don't have a branch for each version, just a tag. wix39r2 is an exception, as we needed a branch for cherry-picking. So yes, getting the file from wix39r2 is fine.